# Unresolved externals error while calling static function

Tags: function, static, externals

This is driving me absolutely nuts. I've tried everything I've found on other posts here, and nothing works... this should NOT be this complicated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class SavingsAccount
{
private:
    float savingsBalance;   
    static float annualInterestRate;

public:

    static void modifyInterestRate(float interestRate)
    {
        annualInterestRate = interestRate;
    }


};

int main()
{
    SavingsAccount::modifyInterestRate(.03);

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Getting an unresolved externals error.

Comment: You've declared `annualInterestRate` in the class but you haven't actually defined it anywhere.

Comment: I tried defining it in the modifyInterestRate function, but I got a scope error.

Comment: Between your class and int main() add float SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate;